# Prove that if n is even, -n is also even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Hi I'm learning how to do proofs out of a book. *Introduction to Proofs* by Jim Hefferson.
I really have some lacking knowledge on proof writing so would like some help verifying correctness and technique of proof.
So let me start this:
If n $\in \mathbb Z$ and n is even, then there is some number $ k \in \mathbb Z$, such that $n=2k$.

Now from here my inclination is to just multiply each side by -1. But I'm not sure if I can just do it or I have to introduce the rule that if you multiply one side by a number you have to multiply the other side by that same number, or maybe I'm just thinking too hard, and in a proof such as this, it would be considered assumed knowledge.

Continuing:
If we multiply each side by -1, we have $(-1)n = (-1)2k$. It follows that $-n=-2k$ and $\frac {-n}{2}=-k $ and n is even.

Does anyone have any comments on this.

Comment: It suffices to show that even times odd is even.

Comment: Ok so I now use the rule that $n,k \in Z$ and $k$ is odd, then $n \times k$ is even. Thus $n \times -1$ is odd. Would this be appropriate?

Comment: You wouldn't have to provide any justification/side-proof for why multiplying both sides by -1 is valid. Such a step is considered an [axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom), or a statement/theorem which has been proven to be true. You could just say "by Algebra".

Comment: Sorry, had to edit that last comment, had odds and evens wrong in the statements.

Comment: aha, "by algebra" I like that. Thankyou.

Comment: I've seen it used in a few texts as pithy justifications for why a certain step was performed :)

Comment: Also, if you're interested, check out the free pdf version of the [Book of Proof](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/BookOfProof.pdf), which has lots of chapters on basic logic and proofs. I'm currently using it to practice in my discrete math course. Good luck in your studies!

Comment: Yeah, I have that one too actually, but I have not looked at that yet. I will have a look at that in parallel with this one I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to finish your argument with $-n = 2(-k)$, which proves that $-n$ is even according to the definition (even = $2$ times an integer).

Comment: That's great, Thanks @lhf.